# Is there a way to save and restore web browser tabs INCLUDING THEIR HISTORY (and other possible tab data) to a text file?

Tags: browser, history, export, browser-tabs, browser-plugin

Upgrading from Linux Mint 18 came with loosing all my navigator tabs. Luckily I had a backup of my old distribution. However, I'm now stuck with it and more and more things stop working.

I know there are plugins to save TABs, but as far as I've searched, most of them will just save the current URL and NOT the **complete state of the TAB (history list, current position, etc)**.

I'd like to know if there exists a known portable way (plugin or preferably script) to save this complete state of one/multiple/all TABs (including history) from a mainstream browser (e.g. firefox) to a readable text file, and to restore them (again, including history) to another mainstream web browser (e.g. Chromium).

Comment: What web browser? Restore state to a different browser, e.g. from Chromium to Firefox?

Comment: Everything about history, settings, etc. of any browser is stored in an hidden folder residing in your user folder. (e.g. Firefox has everything under `.mozilla`). So, it's just a matter of backing up and restoring that folder.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I will check but I think something has changed at that time and that the reason I lost my history in the upgrade.

Comment: If the history has been deleted (it can be) then there's no way other that what was saved with the online sync. If you never set the sync then there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik In my problem there was a change in the way my old browser saved it's tabs, and that the reason it lost it all in the upgrade, but I'd like to find a way which would work between different navigator like as you mentioned : e.g. from Chromium to Firefox

Comment: @ChanganAuto Well, yes, since as I told in the question, I restored a backup of my pre-upgrade system. But I'd like to find a way to save my tab somewhere else, make the upgrade and then restore them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I don't understand what you have trouble understanding : I just want to know if there exists a known way (plugin or script) to take one/multiple/all TABs, and save their whole data (including history) to a text file in order to be able to restore them, on any other well known browser. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Camion Community isn't human.  https://superuser.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Well even so, @Gantendo, if community posted that, it musts come from anonymous people who felt or flagged it that way. So my answer is directed to them ;-)